# Is there an official Apple API for streaming from a Mac app to Apple TV?

Tags: xcode, macos, airplay

I have been searching high and low, but have so far been ineffable. I am now turning for the stackoverflow community for advice.

**My goal is** to build a Mac app in XCode, that will allow me to send MP4 content from my Mac (or from a public URL on the web) to my Apple TV.

I have located numerous classes within the framework for iOS that enables this (quite easily it seems), but the trail ends there. It just seems like there is no API to do the same from OSX, but I am hoping that I have overlooked something :-) There seems to be well established methods for sending *audio* to AirPlay enabled devices, but not video?

I am aware of the 3rd party specification of the protocol at http://nto.github.io/AirPlay.html, and it looks a tangible plan B for my needs, but I would appreciate any pointers if anyone knows of a more official way.

Comment: [There are rumors](http://www.extremetech.com/electronics/201694-report-new-apple-tv-sdk-to-appear-at-wwdc) [that an AppleTV SDK](http://arstechnica.com/apple/2015/03/report-apple-plans-a-new-apple-tv-box-with-an-app-store-and-sdk/) is going to appear (for the first time publicly) at WWDC next week

Comment: @MichaelDautermann, there are also [rumours that it won't appear!](http://www.macrumors.com/2015/06/03/redesigned-apple-tv-not-ready-for-wwdc-debut/)

Comment: @MichaelDautermann: Exciting :-) Sounds like plan B until we hear more from WWDC!